# WebServlet failed to load in Springboot 1.3.1 with EmbeddedTomcat 8

Tags: spring-boot

angular.js: GET 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Following is the code:

1) Maincontroller.js

```
$scope.autologin=function(){
   var username = 'admin';

   var password = 'admin';
   //put here the ajax get to logincheck
   $http.get("/uatload/logincheck?username="+username+"&password="+password)
   .success(function(response) {
          $rootScope.logged = true
          $location.path('/form');                 
   })
   .error(function(){
          $location.path('/error');
   });
};

$scope.autologin();

});
```

2) Logincheck.java(servlet)

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoginCheck", urlPatterns = { "/logincheck" })
public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

//springboot startup class .

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.validatelogin")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class UATLoaderApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

}

However Get request works fine when I navigate through jsp and change url to ("/uatload/logincheck.jsp?username="+username+"&password="+password)

Where logincheck.js

```
<jsp:useBean id="db" class="com.validatelogin.LoginCheck" />
<%

   System.out.println("logincheck CALL");
   db.doGet(request, response);
%>
```

I am using spring boot 1.3.1 with embedded tomcat 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot doesn't scan for `@WebServlet` or `@WebFilter` by default. You need to [use `@ServletComponentScan` to enable it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-scanning):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.validatelogin")
@ServletComponentScan(basePackages="com.validatelogin")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class UATLoaderApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

Comment: @K.Singh What package is `LoginCheck` in? It needs to be in `com.validatelogin` or one of its sub-packages. I also just noticed that I made a typo in my answer (now fixed) where the package name was `com.validatelogic`. To match your `@ComponentScan` annotation it should have been `com.validatelogin`.

Comment: We tried with base package "com.validatelogin" but didn't work.